# .remove is not removing a list item when clicked jquery

Tags: jquery

Why is this not removing a `<li>` when clicked?

```
$(".ListOfItems a").click(function () {
   $(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

This is whereI'm adding list items to the list:

```
      <ul class="ListOfItems">
      </ul>
```

With this:

```
     var list = $(".ListOfItems");

     liToAdd = ("<li id = " + itemtoadd + " class = \"itemAdd\">" + name + 
     "<a href=\"#\" > Remove me</a></li>");
     list.append(liToAdd );
```

Everything's fine but I can't get a  `<li>` to remove.

Comment: Which element is '.ListOfItems' ? Your ul has class "ItemsTotrade"..

Comment: Sorry had wrong name. Updated the code

Comment: You can try removing the li from parent .parent(), like this $(this).parent().remove();

Comment: corrected: `var liToAdd = ("<li id = '" + itemtoadd + "' class = 'itemAdd'>" + name + "<a href='#' > Remove me</a></li>");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using on() method for dynamic DOM elements

```
$('.ListOfItems').on('click','a',function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

CodePen:
http://codepen.io/Maksim/pen/LEAhv

Comment: yes, sorry, on() method to which element you attach it should be already in the html at start, $(document) works always, but if to be more percice you could also use $(".ListOfItems"). Edited my answer also.

Comment: That's my problem with using `document`but this is not working. You're missing the `()` after function also

Comment: made a snippet in CodePen for you, take a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/teBLK
Also made small change in answer

Comment: I don't know what happened. Maybe I wasn't saving but I did the same thing a few mins ago and it didn't work. Anyway, it works now and this is more the way I like to do it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click, ".ListOfItems a", 'function () {
     $(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

Comment: Damn, that was easy. Thank you I've been at this for an hour. Why did it not work with `.ListOfItems a` as the selector?

Comment: I had use .on previously but without `.ListOfItems a`.

Comment: Basically, `click` work for exist element whereas when `on` events is  delegated.